# How to apply diagnostics extension to azure cloud service which is more than 20480 length

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to add diagnostics extension to one of my cloud service in azure, but it is failing due to size of the diagnostics file.

I have to deploy this service from Octopus. I tried deploying the cloud service using 'Deploy azure cloud service' template and then applying the diagnostics using 'Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension'.

```
     Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -DiagnosticsConfiguration $rolesConfig -ServiceName $ServiceName -Verbose -slot $Slot
```

I am expecting that the extensions are applied to cloud service irrespective of the diagnostics extensions length.
Error Message that I get is :- Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension : BadRequest: The maximum length of the extension public configuration is 20480

Answer (score 0):

There is a current issue with Cloud Services. You can read more in the following thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb08c745-c528-430c-86e5-b1cf8759e6ab/unable-to-publish-web-role-in-azure?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

I currently have an internal ticket open to investigate. There is no ETA on when the issue will be resolved however it is being worked on. For other users having similar issues, the work around is to disable the diagnostic extension until the problem is fixed. This will allow you to still publish Cloud Services and update your current services.